# How can I make this code faster where I have to print the total of odds of a given number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

The problem is: Print out how much odd numbers there are in a given number.

```js
function oddCount(n) {
  var odd = [];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
      odd.push([i]);
    }
  }
  return odd.length;
}
console.log(oddCount(8));
```

As we can see, it works properly, however, on codewars, it wants me to optimize it to run faster. Can someone show me how so I can learn it quickly please.

Comment: So you just need to get the number of odd numbers from a given number?

Comment: Since odd and even numbers cycle in order, you could use a division, floored, to determine how many odd. Prime numbers would be a harder problem, which you couldnt do in this way.

Comment: @mardubbles You'll need to divide ceiling to get the number of odds

Comment: Ceiling would work too @Pellay but I was thinking of an if statement to test on `n` being even or odd.

Comment: console.log(Math.ceil(n/2))

Comment: Yes, ceiling, `numberOfOdds = Math.ceil(number/2)`

Comment: @mardubbles, sure, make it more interesting :) I'm interested in what this codewars thing is that so many people come here asking for help with them? Doesn't coming here kind of defeat the point?

Comment: Well, since we're giving the answers away: `oc = n => Math.ceil(n/2);`

Comment: Lol @Pellay yeah its kinda cheating

Answer (score 1):

```
function oddCount(n) {
  var odd = [];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i & 0x1 == 1) {
      odd.push([i]);
    }
  }
  return odd.length;
}
console.log(oddCount(8));
```

or

```
function oddCount(n) {
   return (n - (n & 0x01)) / 2;
}
console.log(oddCount(8));
```

Comment: Neither of these are correct either. 9 returns 4

Answer (score 1):

Neither "ceil" or "floor" is a correct answer as a one liner. "ceil" will make the division Base 1, "floor" will make the division Base 0. So both could be used in an implementation, but the "polarity" of n matters.

It's necessary to check whether the input number is odd or even.

```js
function oddCount(n) {

   // odd / even check
   if (n % 2 == 0) {
     // its even, we can divide by 2
     return n / 2
   }
   else {
     // n is odd, so we must include n as a count+1 itself
     return ((n - 1) / 2) + 1
   }
}

// Disclaimer: Are negative numbers odd or even? In this code they
// apparently aren't handled. So the set of numbers are integers from
// 0 to +Infinity

// Test cases:

console.log( oddCount(8) ); // 4
console.log( oddCount(9) ); // 5
```

But this code "breaks" if n itself is 0 or less. So we need to fix it:

Right after we say `function oddCount(n) {`, put:

```
if (n < 1) return 0;
```

All worries solved. But still debate on whether 0 is odd or even, and whether -1 is odd and -2 is even.

Comment: Love it, though I'd love to see it actually handle infinity. :)

Comment: Wouldn't we all love to see infinity handled, finitely @Pellay. The mysteries of the universe

Comment: This is more clever, but is also a completely new solution, not an improvement of OP's code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.

```js
function oddCount(n) {
  return Math.ceil(n/2);
}
console.log(oddCount(8));
```

Comment: Sniping some free points :D

Comment: Check the comments- needs to be Math.ceil() to account for n being an odd number

Comment: You think it should work, but it doesn't.. input of 9 still returns 4 when there is clearly 5.

Comment: Oh yep, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is an even number, there's n/2 odd numbers
Eg if n is 6
`*1*,2,*3*,4,*5*,6`
If it is an odd number, there's n/2+1 odd numbers. Because n-1 would be even
Eg if n is 5
`*1*,2,*3*,4,  +  *5*`
So basically

```js
if (n%2==0) return n/2
else return (n-1)/2+1
```

The for loops aren't needed
Also like the others pointed out, ceiling is a more concise way to do it

```js
return Math.ceil(n/2)
```

Comment: can't use operator `/` by itself (without floor) because that will return a "float" on odds when division by 2

Comment: Strange looking Javascript :D

Comment: @Pellay xD. Fixed

Comment: @foderking That you did. :D